# Row indices in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

How do I control the row indices in data.table in R?

I want to check if the value in a row matches the previous one:

```
patient    produkt    output
1          Meg        Initiation
1          Meg        Continue
1          Gem        Switch
2          Pol        Initiation
2          Pol        Continue
2          Pol        Continue
```

Where the output column is the output, I wish (could be replaced with numbers if that is easier though such that `initiation=0, continue=1, switch=2`).

I can't find out how to control the indices in data.table, and the following does not work

```
test[ , switcher2 := identical(produkt, produkt[-1]),by=patient]
```

Any ideas are welcome. It has to be in a data.table though.

Comment: Maybe someone knows of a command like diff() but for factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an option using `diff`. I am using `ifelse` to change integer values to characters. Finally , for each group , first element is set to an initial value.

```
setDT(dx)[,output := {
   xx <- ifelse(c(0,diff(as.integer(factor(produkt))))<0,
                "Switch","Continue")
   xx <- as.character(xx)
   xx[1] <- "Initiation"
   xx
   },
patient]

#   patient produkt     output
# 1:       1     Meg Initiation
# 2:       1     Meg   Continue
# 3:       1     Gem     Switch
# 4:       2     Pol Initiation
# 5:       2     Pol   Continue
# 6:       2     Pol   Continue
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I have changed <0 in the second line to !=0 in order to get all switches - the original had output: Initiation ->Switch -> Continue, if the produkt variable changed like this: Meg -> Gem ->Meg. But other than that: Perfect :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt using the new `shift` function from the [devel version on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

I've used the `0:2` notation here as it is shorter to write but you can use words instead

```
test[ , output2 := c(0, (2:1)[(produkt == shift(produkt)) + 1][-1]), by = patient]
#    patient produkt     output output2
# 1:       1     Meg Initiation       0
# 2:       1     Meg   Continue       1
# 3:       1     Gem     Switch       2
# 4:       2     Pol Initiation       0
# 5:       2     Pol   Continue       1
# 6:       2     Pol   Continue       1
```

I'm basically always starting with a `0` per each group and then comparing against the previous value per group. If `TRUE` then `1` is assigned. If `FALSE` then `2` is assigned.

---

If you want it in words, here's alternative verison

```
test[ ,output3 := c("Initiation", c("Switch", "Continue")[(produkt == shift(produkt)) + 1][-1]), by = patient]
```

---

**Installation instructions:**

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```